# Yahoo Movies API Documentation

Tags: api, yahoo-api

I'm trying to use the new unpublished Yahoo Movies API, but can't find any documentation, official or unofficial, about it.

Does anyone know if any documentation exists for this?

sample API call:
http://new.api.movies.yahoo.com/v2/listMovies?title=Transformers

EDIT: The API can no longer be accessed. I'm not sure what Yahoo's plans are with this API. Any info would help.

Comment: How did you find out about that? Just curious.

Comment: i was looking for a api or a source of movie information and just found this on google

Answer (score 2):

Can't really help you with your original question, as all links now seem to be dead!

However, using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) you might still be able to achieive what you are trying to do.

> What's YQL? select * from internet
> The Yahoo! Query Language (YQL) platform enables developers to query, filter, and combine data across the web. YQL exposes a SQL-like syntax that is both familiar to developers and expressive enough for getting the right data.

There is also a listing of community provided tables that you can make use of which can be found at http://www.datatables.org/

To make use of this, all you have to do is import the community tables in to the online YQL console or follow this handy link [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env) which will give you a list of all tables from datatables.org and access to them from the YQL console.

I've had a quick search through this for tables marked as movies so here are some queries you can try out to get further information! Although most of them are from nyt and require an api key, but yahoo seem to have taken care of that for us - information [here](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2009/10/yql_now_with_ap.html) and a link to the console with this data imported is [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys) so for the bellow examples, you are probably best using that link.

> select * from movies.showtimes
>
> select * from nyt.movies.critics
>
> select * from nyt.movies.reviews where reviewer="VINCENT CANBY"

As I don't know enough about what you want the data for, I don't know if any of this information will be of use, but I'm hoping that it is :]

Comment: I've posted a related question here, but haven't had any takers yet.  Any chance you could take a look?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681153/looking-for-help-with-yql-movie-showtimes

Comment: thanks for the very good answer. unfortunately the data i'm looking for is not available in a public database yet. I need actual movie metadata (synopsis, release date, actors, directors, genres, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

Moe, did you see this post over in their forums? http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=1646

You might want to pursue that thread of discussion to see if you can get any information from Jon or if Nate received any information (but based on his post today, sounds like he didn't get any further).

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that discussion thread. There doesn't seem to be any useful information there.

Comment: You're right, which, since someone from Yahoo! posted on it (albeit not from that project), I don't think that looks too good about getting documentation at this point in time.

Comment: Thread has disappeared(!) but Google cache still available: http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:dC_dx5H4ih4J:developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php%3Fshowtopic%3D1646+yahoo+movie+api&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=safari

Comment: And it's out of Google's cache ...

Answer (score 0):

I've asked someone I know at YDN, he's not sure but he said he'll find out. I'll update this answer with info as I hear it :)

**EDIT:** I'm sorry he can't seem to find out any more info... I had high hopes!