# Looking for help with YQL movie showtimes

Tags: yql, movies

I had been using the undocumented Yahoo movies API until it was pulled a few days ago, so I'm looking for another way to retrieve local movie showtimes (ideally by theater).  I found **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329377/yahoo-movies-api-documentation/1655952#1655952)** about YQL datatables on SO, and the last post looked really promising.  I just can't seem to figure out how to query the data to return local movies and showtimes. I've been trying variations on "SELECT * from movies.showtimes where location='myzip'" with no success.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select * from movies.showtimes`

To get a list of all movies. Then:

```
select * from movies.showtimes with location='myzip' and name='one of the movies'
```

You could also do

```
select * from movies.showtimes with location='myzip' and name in whatever
```

There's no list by location, unfortunately

Comment: For some reasons, this query does not work in YQL console anymore.